# Can you get rid of the trace labels in the annotations when using ggplotly (ggplot2 with plotly)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

is it possible to remove the trace labels in the annotations when using ggplotly?

For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

g <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 4, xmax = 5, ymin = 4, ymax = 5,
           colour = "MediumSeaGreen", fill = "MediumSeaGreen", alpha = 0.3)

ggplotly(g)
```

Here, how would I get rid of the 'trace 1' when I hover over the green box? I would like to keep the hover on the points though.

[image: box]

Note: Also posted here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/can-you-get-rid-of-the-trace-labels-in-the-annotations-when-using-ggplotly-ggplot2-with-plotly/129754

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `style` and specifying `hoverinfo` as follows:

```
ggplotly(g) %>%
  style(hoverinfo = "skip")
```

Note you can use "none" or "skip" to hide the tooltip with hover. If `none` or `skip` are set, no information is displayed upon hovering. But, if `none` is set, click and hover events are still fired.

You can also indicate which traces you'd like this to apply to. If none are explicitly included, then it will apply to all traces.

To remove the annotation `hoverinfo` for a specific geom, you can try this:

```
gg <- ggplotly(g)
gg$x$data[[2]]$hoverinfo <- "none"
gg
```

Reference: https://plotly.com/r/reference/#layout

Comment: Thanks for the response Ben. However that also gets rid of the hover info on the points. I would like to keep the ones on the points, but remove the one on the dots. I'll update the   question.

Comment: Actually, I didn't read the last bit properly. Will have more of a loook.

Comment: @william3031 See edited answer - does this work for you?