# R Plotly: Remove trace from tooltip in subplot

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to have two plotly boxplots side by side using subplot. My problem is that, I cannot get rid of the trace information in the tooltip.

```
library(plotly)

fig1 <- plot_ly(
  y = list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 
  q1=list(1, 2, 3),
  median=list(4, 5, 6),
  q3=list(7, 8, 9),
  type = "box",
  fillcolor = "#4FA645",
  line = list(color = 'darkgreen'))

fig2 <- fig1

subplot(fig1, fig2) |>   layout(showlegend = F)
```

I would like to remove the #4FA645 tooltip part. See below.

[image]

I figured out so far that this might be achievable by using hovertemplate and pasting an <extra></extra> behind whatever is written there but I did not figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most elegent solution but I found one myself to solve the problem.

```
pp <- subplot(fig1, fig2) |> layout(showlegend = F)

pp$x$data[[1]]$name <- " "
pp$x$data[[2]]$name <- " "

pp
```

This [answer and question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71213317/can-you-get-rid-of-the-trace-labels-in-the-annotations-when-using-ggplotly-ggpl) helped me solve my problem.